# Pulseaudio and two cards, how to select card from command line?

Tags: pulseaudio

I have three sinks, which are 3 different soundcards
0 is USB speaker
1 is integrated
2 is hdmi

With those commands

```
pacmd list-sinks
pacmd set-default-sink 0
pacmd set-default-source 0
pacmd set-sink-volume 0 35000
```

I can select the sink n°0 but no sound arrive because the card number 1 is still active(pulseaudio list it as suspended).
The question is: which command to turn off the card number 1?

Comment: How did you determine that "no sound arrives because the card number 1 is still active"? Or "pulseaudio lists it as suspended"? There are at least three commands being described here, why not tell us what they are and show the output?

Comment: The card is still active because the command pactl list short sinks show it as suspended.If (from a gui program) I disable it the usb card became the default and I can hear sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get the correct card index

```
pacmd list-cards
```

Assuming the index is 1 you can turn it off like this:

```
pacmd set-card-profile 1 off
```